# adb push ... Permission denied

Tags: adb, file-permissions

I am trying to push a file to a directory on a physical android device, but I am running into the following error.

```
>adb push data.db /data/data/com.me.app/databases
failed to copy 'data.db' to '/data/data/com.me.app/databases/data.db': Permission denied
```

I believe adb has sufficient privileges.

```
>adb root
adbd is already running as root
```

Here are the permission details for the path: /data/data/com.me.app/databases

```
drwxrwxrwx system   system            2014-01-14 10:31 data
drwxrwxrwx system   system            2015-05-23 16:06 data
drwxrwxrwx u0_a224  u0_a224           2015-05-23 15:26 com.me.app
drwxrwxrwx u0_a224  u0_a224           2015-05-23 15:30 databases
```

I am not sure what to do here. Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way, but I just want to push the data.db file into the /data/data/com.me.app/databases directory on the device.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or what I should consider? Thanks.

Comment: Put your workaround as an answer here, and accept your own answer so people looking for a similar problem will see it answered when they search for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit: I found a work-around:** [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en) allows me to upload the file, but the permissions on the file are set to this:

```
-rw-------
```

Performing the following commands solves this problem (from Windows 7 command prompt).

```
>adb shell
# su
# chmod 777 /data/data/com.me.app/databases/data.db
```

Answer (score 4):

The usual approach, which doesn't require any additional apps:

1. Push to `/data/tmp/`;
2. Copy on the device using `adb shell`, using `cp` if it's available on your device or `cat` if it isn't.

   ```
    > adb push data.db /data/tmp/data.db
    > adb shell
    # su # or run-as com.me.app
    # cp /data/tmp/data.db /data/data/com.me.app/databases/data.db
   ```

Remembering to change `com.me.app` to the correct package name for your app.

Comment: This approach worked for me. For completeness, I actually pushed an obb file to `/sdcard/` and then used `adb shell` without root permissions to copy this file to the correct package folder for this file (in `/sdcard/Android/obb/packagename/` where `packagename` needs to be changed to match that of your Android app.

Comment: I had to create it first: `adb shell mkdir /data/tmp/ ; adb shell chmod 777 /data/tmp/ ; adb push file /data/tmp/`

Answer (score 4):

I had a variation of this problem so going to leave it here in case someone else googles for it:

```
./adb push update.zip /sdcard
[  0%] C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/sdcard
adb: error: failed to copy 'update.zip' to 'C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/sdcard':
remote secure_mkdirs failed: No such file or directory
update.zip: 0 files pushed. 41.6 MB/s (131072 bytes in 0.003s)
```

However in my case the problem was running `adb` from Git bash Shell (MinGW64). Running it from regular Windows shell worked fine.