# adb permission denied to push files to subdirectry

Tags: adb

Why would I get permission denied using adb to copy a directory to a subdirectory on my phone, when I could copy to its parent directory and both have the same permission?

I tried this from my PC to my Nexus 5 running 6.0.1 (Oct 5):

```
adb push Dir /sdcard/Dir/Subdir
```

It failed with

```
Permission denied
```

This has worked before, with no changes I'm aware of.

I launched adb shell and ran

```
ls -l
```

to get permissions for /sdcard (storage/emulated/0), /sdcard/Dir and /sdcard/Dir/Subdir:

```
drwxrwx--x root sdcard_rw
```

I then:

```
cd /sdcard/Dir/Subdir
mkdir XYZ
```

Got

```
mdkdir: XYZ: Permission Denied
```

Tried:

```
su
mkdir XYZ
```

Again, permission denied

I then tried another push

```
adb push XYZ /sdcard/Dir
```

This worked and copied all of the files.

Why would it work to /sdcard/Dir and not to /sdcard/Dir/Subdir, when both have the same permissions?  Why would permission be denied for root?

Comment: Did you create that subdir when browsed into /data/media/0/Dir/? Either way, please provide the output of `su -c 'ls -l /data/media/0/Dir/Subdir'` and compare the permissions with the rest of the subdirs there.

Comment: @Firelord I did not create the subdirectry when browsed there. The entire directory tree (/sdcard/Dir) was created by an adb push.  Permissions for Dir are dwrxrwxr-x media_rw media_rw, while Subdir are  dwrxrwxr-x root root.  When using plain ls -l on storage/emulated/0, I get  dwrxrwx--x root sdcard_rw on Dir?

Comment: Could you change the permission of /data/media/0/Dir/Subdir to rwxrwxrwx, or alternatively, change the user group from root to media_rw? Make  sure to run the operations on the /data/media/0/.. path and no  /storage/emulated/..

Comment: @Firelord That worked (chmod 777).  Thank you. What's the difference between /data/media/0 and /storage/emulated or /sdcard?    The each appear to contain the same files?

Comment: /data/media is the real path in EXT4 filesystem. /storage hosts the FAT style emulated /data/media which you and the apps can read and write into. I do not know the reason behind this emulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it appears in [this comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159953/adb-permission-denied-to-push-files-to-subdirectry#comment204615_159953), the file permissions and access control to SubDir differs from what ideally should be.

The problem:

```
# ls -l on /data/media/0/Dir
dwrxrwxr-x root root
```

The user group should have been *media_rw* instead of *root*.

The solution is to change to appropriate group or make the directory writable by others.

```
chmod 777 /data/media/0/Dir/SubDir       # making SubDir writable by others
chgrp media_rw /data/media/0/Dir/SubDir  # Alternatively, changing group from root to media_rw
```

**Note:** you may need to install Busybox or Toybox to have and use chmod and/or chgrp.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar problem reported in [adb push ... Permission denied](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110162/adb-push-permission-denied) where I ended up pushing the file to `/sdcard/` and then used `adb shell` to then copy the file to the sub-directory I needed it to be in.

For completeness:

Let's assume I have an expansion file `test.obb` file I want to install on a local physical Android device, and my package name of the app is `app.example.test`.

I pushed the file using `adb push` e.g.
`adb push test.obb /sdcard/`

`adb shell`

```
cd /sdcard/Android/obb/app.example.test/
cp /sdcard/test.obb .
ls -la
```

I can now see the obb file is in the folder it needs to be in.